# What are the chances for a new level with the salvage droid missions?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

With the Feb 28, 2014 update, there now is the Salvage Droid mechanism for obtaining rewards.  As far as I can tell, there is one free chance each day but otherwise it costs Imperial Bux to have a chance for a reward.  There are three possible levels: "a chance"  (5 bux), "good chance" for 15 box and the "best chance" for 25 bux.

Question 1: Does anyone have data about what the chances are for obtaining "rare" rewards with each type of mission?

What would be good to know particularly is the chance of getting a new level, and which levels are unlockable via this mechanism.

Question 2: Do the destinations for droids make any difference?  There have been "debris field" and "asteroid field" listed, and the presence of the "rescan" purchase suggests that there is some difference, but I don't know what that would be.

Comment: So far, I've done the free one and a "best" chance but both rewards have been underwhelming (about 10 Imperial items of two types, which I already had many of.) I would like to get whatever additional levels are feasible by this mechanism, but I don't know if this is a good way of proceeding or if this will just use up bux to not much effect.

Comment: Further, it sounds like from the description that this will only be available for 3 days. It would also be helpful to know which levels are possible rewards. For me, there are 8 locked levels in the album, not purchasable yet: Panna City Medicines, Chiss Hospital, Endor Adventure, Kashyyyk Shack, Endor Arms, Csilla Apts, Wookie Arms, and the Overbridge imperial level.  Perhaps Kashyyyk Shack is available since the splash screen mentioned Kashyyyk but I do not know if any of the others are available or if they will be unlocked in the coming weeks through the normal course of events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panna city med was from the Christmas event, so I don't think they'll make that available again.
From what I can tell, if you see a planet (Kashyyyk, endor, etc...) and you click on it, you'll get a graphic showing what you might be able to get. For instance, Kashyyyk shows two characters and a level.
However, you have to purposefully search on that particular planet/area to possibly get that reward. Rescan (every 12 hours, or on demand for 5 bux) rearranges your scanning options. You get one free scan on the first area once a day or on demand for 5 bux; but I have not seen a planet on that scanning level. Essentially what that means is that you can't get these rewards without using bux. Which sux.

Comment: When I got a "rescan" I got Kashyyyk to show up for the 25 bux droid.  I've used 275 bux on it, and received: 3 new bitizens (all Wookies, but different), and then a bunch of utter crap (like 1 celebrity, or a couple pieces of Imperial equipment.  Ugh.).  I really want to unlock the level, but the ability to generate bux is so slow that I doubt I'll be able to do it - especially since Kashyyyk is going to rotate out when the level "rescans".  This is brutal.

Comment: I have Kashyyyk on the 5 bux level, so it's possible. Not sure if you're better off with it there for cheaper scans or at 15 or 25 for better chance of good stuff, though.

Comment: Almost as bad as spending 25 bux for a single Celebrity... spending 25 bux to get 5 bux back.  This mini-game is brutal.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Question 2, if you click the magnifying glass next to the location name, it will actually show you a picture of what possible rewards there are.  It basically looks like Asteroid Field and Debris Field are a waste of bux.  Kashyyyk has 2 colored in Wookies and a level, and 3 "missing" characters.  I've unlocked 3 wookies via Kashyyyk so I imagine that there are 5 total characters to unlock from there, and 1 level.

Answer (score 1):

sillaKashyyyk doesn't "rotate out" when you rescan, but it may change position (go from 25 bux to 15 bux or 5 bux/free). That's what the rescan does, is shuffle. So far the options I've seen are Kashyyyk (may appear more than once, in any slot), Debris Field (may appear in any slot, but only seen one at a time), and Shipwreck (only seen once).

Going by the magnifying glass, Kashyyyk gives you the chance to get a couple of named Wookiees, some hidden characters (more Wookiees?), levels (Wookiee Arms is the one shown, but Kashyyyk Shack is probably possible as well), or loot (credits, bux, VIPs, costumes).

Debris Field appears to just award loot, but it might be a catch-all, based on the name.

Shipwreck gives the chance to get a white protocol droid, a red/white astromech (round dome, so probably an R2), a couple of hidden droids (looks like the "Gonk" droid and the blue one with the long arms from Luke's moisture farm), and loot.

It did say it would be at Kashyyyk for 72 hours, so after that it will probably cycle to Endor or the Chiss planet (based upon level names).

I've gotten nothing but junk so far (nothing better than a Big Spender VIP, which I got free), and have dropped 75 bux into the 25 slot, so it looks like this is their hard sell to try to get people to buy bux. This will be confirmed if they don't continue the salvage minigame after only one pass of the current batch of planets. Best bet I'm thinking is to try to rescan and get Kashyyyk (or the current planet) into the free spot and try your luck on that, unless you have a ton of bux stored up that you don't mind wasting the majority of.

Comment: During the first rotation that I had in-game, Kashyyyk was not present.  It only appeared on the 25 bux spot during the second rotation (and stayed there on the third).